# Yarn retornando erro ao tentar adicionar o "cors"

Tags: node.js, cors, yarn

Fala Devs :D

Estou tendo um erro que está me incomodando um pouco...

Ao tentar adicionar o pacote "cors" pelo yarn, o terminal me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
$ yarn add cors
yarn add v1.16.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
error An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\\RafaWorks\\CURSOS\\OMNI Stack Aulas\\backend\\node_modules\\sharp\\
build\\Release\\libcroco-0.6-3.dll'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "E:\\RafaWorks\\CURSOS\\OMNI Stack Aulas\\backend\\yarn-e
rror.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Não estou entendendo o porquê está ocorrendo erro de incompatibilidade e não consigo achar a solução.

Agradeço desde já a atenção de vocês!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia a todos,

descobri hoje pela manhã o problema, era um conflito que existia ao tentar adicionar o **cors** com o `yarn dev` do *nodemon* rodando.
Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema que tive, é só parar o terminal que está rodando o `yarn dev`, a instalação vai ir até o fim com sucesso.

Ah e se mesmo assim o problema persistir, reinicie o computador, abra o seu terminal **como administrador** e tente rodar novamente na pasta do seu projeto o comando `yarn add cors`.